# React Native - StatusBar color iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I can't set the color of the status bar on iOS and Android on React Native with Expo.
I just managed to hide it.

Code :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native'

export default class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return <>
         <StatusBar hidden={true} />
         <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://foo.co' }} style={{ marginTop: 33 }} />
      </>
   }
}
```

I already tried :

```
<StatusBar hidden={false} barStyle="light-content" />
```

and :

```
<StatusBar barStyle = "dark-content" hidden = {true} backgroundColor = "#00BCD4" translucent = {true}/>
```

I am really confused about how this StatusBar works.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

the backgroundColor prop change your StatusBar color, the problem with your last example is that you used hidden={true}

```
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';

<StatusBar backgroundColor="#00BCD4" />
```

For expo, you shoud configure `app.json`
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/configuring-statusbar/

Comment: I also tried without the "hidden" property and it still doesn't work. Edit : work just for Android :)

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see you're using expo, try this: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/configuring-statusbar/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the StatusBar background color in iOS. However, there’s a work-around, i.e, you have to define the background color of the header in the Stack Navigator of @react-navigation/stack

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

//Pages
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";

const AppLoad = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <AppLoad.Navigator initialRouteName='Dashboard'>
          <AppLoad.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard}
              options={{
                headerTitle: null,
                headerLeft: null,
                headerStyle: {
                  backgroundColor: '#0891b2',
                  shadowColor: 'transparent',
                  elevation: 0,
                  height: 48,
                },
              }}/>
        </AppLoad.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    )
  }
```

[image: Expo SDK50]